# laravel Redirect::to() loses the port

Tags: php, nginx, laravel, laravel-4

I'm running my development environment through vagrant (Ubuntu, nginx, php-fpm) and accessing the server on localhost:8080. I'm using Laravel 4 and trying to set up my authentication system. It seems that Laravel just ignores the port you are using if you are using an alternative port. Is this true? For example, when I run a redirect from `http://localhost:8080/login` to `/profile` I end up on `http://localhost/profile`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can fix/patch this?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this? I have the reversed problem, Laravel adds a port when I redirect... Probably due to my crazy server config, but still need to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This smells like a bug.  I get stuck digging in the UrlGenerator when it looks for the [`request->root()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php#L274).  From what I can see there is no `root()` function on the [Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L917-927).  You could try replacing `->root()` with `->getBaseUrl()` instead.

Regardless of the outcome, you should prepare a small test case (with as little excess code as possible) and report the [issue on GitHub](http://github.com/laravel/framework/issues) to be fixed.  If you can find a solution while you're at it then a pull request can be made to fix the issue.